# How to use mocks in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I know that there are tutorials and other posts about mocks in Python but I'm new to testing and mocks, I read some posts and watched a tutorial but they confused me more. I have two examples that I just wrote fast and I wanna know how can I use mocks to test two examples.

In the first example test the the value that gets returned and in the second one test that a file gets created if we create a new instance of the 'MyFile' class.

## 1:

```
def get_link_tags(url):
    response = requests.get(url)

    pattern = re.compile("<link.*>")
    found_link_tags = pattern.findall(response.text)
    return found_link_tags
```

## 2:

```
class MyFile:
    def __init__(self, filename, content):
        self.content = content

        with open(filename, "w") as fl:
            fl.write(content)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you want to mock `requests.get` so that you can control its return value. Since `requests.get` is actually a Mock object
when you call `get_link_tags`, its return value will be as well, so you can configure its `text` attribute to be whatever data you want.

```
with mock.patch('requests.get') as mock_get:
    mock_get.return_value.text = "my test data"
    rv = get_link_tags("http://example.com")
```

The second example is a little tricker; the `mock` library provides a function to make it simpler.

```
m = mock.mock_open()
with mock.patch('__main__.open', m):
    f = MyFile('foo.txt', 'data')
    h = m()
    h.write.assert_called_once_with('data')
```

`m` is a mock object that replaces `open` everywhere in the body of the `with` statement. The key thing to note is that when `m` is called both inside `MyFile` and manually in the next line, a reference to the *same* mock object is returned. This lets you test how the fake file inside `MyFile` is used.

Comment: Since there are not any `<link>` tags in `response.text` (which now is the string `"my test data"`) the `get_link_tags` will return an empty list. Is `self.assertEqual(rv, [])` appropriate to complete the test or should any of the `mock` assert methods be called?

Comment: In this case, `self.assertEqual` is fine, since you aren't concerned with the actual behavior of the mock so much as what the rest of `get_link_tags` does with the data the mock returns. Ideally, you would have multiple tests, each one setting `mock_get.return_value.text` to different values, to confirm that `get_link_tags` does the right thing with each.

Comment: One thing you might do with the mock object, for example, is verify that it is called with the argument passed to `get_link_tags`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.